# Building custom pages with a video player

Tags: plugins, functions, attachments, video-player

Hey i am trying to learn wordpress developement on my own, I'm building a celebrity gossip blog and i need help.

I want to build a video page.

Does anyone know of a plugin or anything that i can use that allows me to have a flash video player that also accepts youtube links as well.

Something like, Inserting the video url, youtube if needed, and information about the video, and when i'm done i save it, and it has it's own video page that i can link to.

for example this link below has a list of video post:

http://www.celebuzz.com/video/

and when you click on the links it goes to a single video page like the link below

http://www.celebuzz.com/video-post/sneak-preview-of-%e2%80%98austin-ally%e2%80%99-%e2%80%94-%e2%80%98world-records-work-wreckers%e2%80%99-episode/

Or would i have to create a special post type for videos.

I would deeply appreciate it if someone could give me an answer to this question, it would make me extremely ecstatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at Tubepress - http://tubepress.org/ ?

Then you could create a new category and a custom layout for that category.

Comment: I just decided to use custom post pages, but thanks, also Tubepress isn't exactly what i was looking for.